# running opensuse:13.1 docker image but it's showing me ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, opensuse

I am running opensuse:13.1 docker image but it's showing me ubuntu in "uname -a" command. Just want to know is this issue with SuSe's docker image or Something from my side.

```
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker-emr# docker run -it opensuse:13.1                                      bash
bash-4.2# uname -a
Linux 3e52b37a2610 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash-4.2#
```

---

Even tried with Dockerfile :

```
# cat Dockerfile
FROM opensuse:13.1

#MAINTAINER <your name> "<your email>"

# make sure the repositories are up to date
RUN zypper --non-interactive --gpg-auto-import-keys ref

RUN zypper in -y vim
```

Buid :

```
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker-opensuse# docker build -t ashishkarpe/my-opensuse:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM opensuse:13.1
 ---> b8cb6b50a4a2
Successfully built b8cb6b50a4a2
```

Commands :

```
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker-opensuse# docker run -it ashishkarpe/my-opensuse:1.0 bash
bash-4.2# uname -a
Linux febbf7acc931 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ref : https://news.opensuse.org/2014/08/07/official-docker-containers/

PS : Is zypper available in suse only ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers use their host's kernel, which is why you're seeing an Ubuntu-provided kernel. If you need a true virtualization solution where you can use separate kernels, look into KVM.